# Sonar default rules

Tags: sonarqube

I want to rename default rules in Sonar, like rule File name.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: The C plugin is deprecated. I guess you won't get much help then. Moreover, even if it is an actual issue, it won't be fixed. I recommend you to move to the C/C++ plugin: http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/languages/cpp/

Answer (score 0):

Go to the settings -> Quality Profiles -> Click on the profile that has the rules that you want to deactivate. The rules are in the coding rules tab. Then deselect (deactivate) the rules that you do not want.
You can also use the filter criteria and do bulk deactivation.

Comment: Thanks prakash, but i don't want that. I want to rename default rules that you can use when you download, for example, Java language.